# How can I make this image fit on mobile portrait view while maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, debugging

I'm really confused.  For some reason, my code just simply allow this happen.  If I put `height: auto;`, the image disappears so I'm forced to put in a number manually, for example, 700px. Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrauzs6m/16/) for reference

How would I maintain this image's width and height in portrait view on mobile?

HTML:

```
<div style="background-image: url(&quot;https://mario.nintendo.com/static/fd723b2893d4d2b39ef71bfdb4e3329c/579b4/mario-background.png&quot;);" class="cpi-wall-detailed-image"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.cpi-wall-detailed-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 768px;
}
```

Comment: As the image is a background you need to size it using background-size. Depending on what you want either use contain, when the whole image will be seen, or cover when the image will cover the div with top/bottom or sides cropped as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
.cpi-wall-detailed-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 768px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .cpi-wall-detailed-image {
  zoom:0.5
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 475px) {
  .cpi-wall-detailed-image {
  zoom:0.4
}
}
```

Comment: That seem to be a great start but it look like `zoom`'s still increasing the width of the image despite it being 100% whenever I try :(.  I just need to increase vertically (height).

Answer (score 0):

try this then :

```
.cpi-wall-detailed-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2316px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .cpi-wall-detailed-image {
  zoom:0.37
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 475px) {
  .cpi-wall-detailed-image {
  zoom:0.325
}
}
```